# A placeholder text to tableview if the datasource is empty

Tags: ios, uitableview, uikit

I want to display a text to user to inform that there is no content in the data source. For example you can see this kind of behavior in contacts App if you don't have contacts it says it at the middle of the table with gray text. Is there easy way to do this or do I have to use some trick like creating empty cells or something.. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There isn't (AFAIK) any built-in way to have a table view display a message when empty. You could have `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` return 1 if the datasource is empty and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` return a "dummy" cell saying there is no data. Or you could just add your own view to display the appropriate message, ignoring the (empty) table view completely.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a short and sweet solution.

First step, in your UITableViewController initialization, add:

```
UILabel *placeholder = [[UILabel alloc] init];
placeholder.font = [placeholder.font fontWithSize:20];
placeholder.numberOfLines = 0; // Use as many lines as needed.
placeholder.text = NSLocalizedString(@"Your text here", nil);
placeholder.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
placeholder.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

placeholder.hidden = YES; // Initially hidden.
[self.tableView addSubview:placeholder];

self.placeholder = placeholder; // You'll need a reference to the placeholder.
```

Second step, in your UITableViewController, add:

```
- (void)viewWillLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewWillLayoutSubviews];

    self.placeholder.frame = self.tableView.bounds;
}
```

Last step, show/hide the placeholder when needed.

A better solution would be not using UITableViewController. Just add a tableView to a UIViewController and add a placeholder view to the UIViewController above the tableView. Use Auto Layout to have the placeholder centered vertically and horizontally. Finally, show/hide the placeholder when needed.

What do you guys think about that solution? Please comment.

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, implementing it in Swift. I have a question though. The last step "show/hide the placeholder when needed". To do that, inside `tableView(_:numberOfRowsInSection:)`, before returning the number of rows in my table, I've included: `placeholder.hidden = myDataSource.count > 0` and just with that it works as I wanted, but I wonder if it is the right place to be including code. Or if that function is intended _only_ to return the number of rows, with no extra code.

Answer (score 6):

In Swift 2.0

just below the calendar , I have a tableview

[image: disregard the calendar]

```
func TabelaSemDados(Array:NSArray){
    if Array.count == 0 {
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

        var label = UILabel()
        label.frame.size.height = 42
        label.frame.size.width = tableView.frame.size.width
        label.center = tableView.center
        label.center.y = (tableView.frame.size.height/2)
        label.numberOfLines = 2
        label.textColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        label.text = "No Data Text"
        label.textAlignment = .Center
        label.tag = 1

        self.tableView.addSubview(label)
    }else{
        self.tableView.viewWithTag(1)?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

called viewdidapper:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    TabelaSemDados(self.Agenda)
}
```

Comment: this is a very clean solution, if your tableview is not going from the left edge to the right edge you need to add the frames origin to the labels center

Answer (score 2):

I wrote up [three different approaches in my blog](http://blog.yangmeyer.de/ios-dev/2013/05/11/best-practice-handling-empty-table-views.html):

- go with the simple solution described by Anomie: use conditionals in your datasource methods.
- use a "magical" do-it-all category [UITableView+NXEmptyView](https://github.com/nxtbgthng/UITableView-NXEmptyView).
- use a separate datasource class for special cases (empty, loading, …).

Comment: I don't get the implementatoin in your blog the  tableView numberOfRowsInSection will return 1 even if there is no view, and then you do  if ([tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] > 0)  to check if the number is higher than 0 which I believe it will alway be since you are returning 1 as the default, could you explain this solution?

Comment: The idea is that you have a separate data source for when the table view is empty. In your view controller, if the underlying data changes (e.g. user added/deleted something), you check which data source applies.

Comment: I have to say this solution is terrible after checking the NXEmptyView category out. It swizzled the reloadData and layoutSubviews method in a CATEGORY, how can you ensure the caller not doing same hacking method? I through the same solution out before but I prefer to build a stand-alone empty view class for my custom tableview.

Comment: Another one minus for NSExmptyView - https://github.com/nxtbgthng/UITableView-NXEmptyView/issues/13

Answer (score 0):

Please look [here](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=empty)

I can suggest to pay your attention at [DZNEmptyDataSet](https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNEmptyDataSet), [StatefulViewController](https://github.com/aschuch/StatefulViewController), [UIEmptyState](https://github.com/luispadron/UIEmptyState) and [StatusProvider](https://github.com/mariohahn/StatusProvider)

But this libs are big and in most cases you can use [@Pablo Ruan](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34795782/5790492)'s answer